# trigger Joomla's rokbox with jquery

Tags: jquery, joomla

I'm trying to open the rokbox login module through jquery. I want the pop up to appear as soon as the page (and the js) loads.

Normally the popup is triggered when a url is clicked which looks like this:

```
<a rel="rokbox[355 385][module=rt-popuplogin]" href="#">Login</a>
```

How would i trigger the pop up to appear with jquery?

I already tried using the click and trigger events with no avail. That line of html is btw loaded on the page. I just need to trigger the click event which doesn't seem to work...

It is wrapped in a span with id `#login` so I selected the child with `.find("a")` and then binding the click to it, but nothing.. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider something like that to use native JavaScript handlers:

```
if (document.createEvent) {
    jQuery('#login').find('a').get(0).dispatchEvent('click');
} else {
    jQuery('#login').find('a').get(0).fireEvent('click');
}
```

More details in this topic: [How to trigger event in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-)
in-javascript

Comment: This almost worked. I changed the dispatch and fireevent to just .click() and it worked :)